# Can I restore one partition of OS X El Capitan?

Tags: bootcamp, partition, macos

I'm trying to install Windows 10 on El Capitan using Boot Camp, I could create the partition, but I need to remove this partition. When I try to enter in Boot Camp again, it shows next error:

> You can not divide the boot disk partitions or restore a single partition.
>
> To install Windows, the boot disk must be formatted as a single volume Mac OS Extended (Journaled) or be partitioned by Boot Camp Assistant.

If I access on terminal with diskutil:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Javier:~ pecete$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            88.3 GB    disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS Blank                   32.0 GB    disk0s4
/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh              +88.0 GB    disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 706C3648-CE21-42FE-9D06-17158DD26E5F
                                 Unencrypted
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *62.2 GB    disk2
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 PCT@HOME                62.2 GB    disk2s1
```

I need to remove the partition "Apple_HFS", so I want to link "Apple_HFS" with "Apple_CoreStorage".

More information:

```
+-- Logical Volume Group FACD278F-4F66-423F-B262-03E39BA793A7
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         88348913664 B (88.3 GB)
    Free Space:   94208 B (94.2 KB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 7E9E18B9-E2B8-4B99-95C5-CF17BB1BD988
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     88348913664 B (88.3 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family F9B1898F-B0B3-43AB-8E45-F16F85DF582A
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
        Encryption Status:       Unlocked
        Conversion Status:       Converting
        Reversion State:         Pending
        High Level Queries:      Not Fully Secure
        |                        Has Visible Users
        |                        Has Volume Key
        |
        +-> Logical Volume 706C3648-CE21-42FE-9D06-17158DD26E5F
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk1
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          87996497920 B (88.0 GB)
            Conversion Progress:   Paused
            Revertible:            Yes (unlock and decryption required)
            LV Name:               Macintosh 
            Volume Name:           Macintosh 
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

I need to reach removing this partition of 32 GB.

Comment: The error was that when I was trying to execute the command "diskUtil eraseVolume" occurred an error because the data storage was protected with FileVault.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try removing the disk partition with Disk Utility?  Bootcamp can be difficult with these things once you've had a first attempt.

Did you know you don't need Bootcamp necessarily to install Windows?  You can create the partitions yourself and activate the install by booting from your USB stick image.  Just need to be sure that you have got the drivers for Windows 10 to hand from Bootcamp once Windows is installed.

All the best!